# efibootmgr in case of lose power

Tags: linux, boot, uefi

Lets say my boot entries look like below:

```
efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002
Boot0001* UEFI OS HD(1,GPT,dd09316a-c79c-4f0d-9ce3-aa67462b9f24,0x800,0x9000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0002* UEFI: Generic Flash Disk 2.00 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x15,0x0)/USB(1,0)..BO
```

Now I adding new entry: `efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -L GRUB-CUSTOM -l /EFI/GRUB/bootx64.efi`

What if I lose power during invoke above command before data will be stored in non-volatile memory ? EFI check integrity of each variable and just this new one will be ignore ?

Comment: Are you asking out of sheer curiosity, or is there another reason for it?

Comment: There is another reason. I am planning to upgrade grub bootloader on remote devices without physical access. When new version of bootloader appear on the server the devices should discovered that and download and use new one. I want to avoid situation when something goes wrong and device would not boot up correctly..